# scope.$watch not invoked by AngularJS directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have the following `link` function in an **AngularJS** directive:

```
 link: function(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
        scope.$watch('name', function(newVal){
            if(newVal){
                console.log(newVal);  
            }
        }, true);
    }
```

The full fiddle is located here: http://jsfiddle.net/balteo/K4t7P/55/

I am trying to figure out why the `$watch` function is not invoked when a user changes the `name` variable in the textarea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a new scope when you write this on your directive

```
scope: {
    name: '='
}
```

Just remove it and all will work well

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K4t7P/56/)

### Explanation

About the scope attribute, in the [docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile), we read:

> If set to {} (object hash), then a new "isolate" scope is created. The 'isolate' scope differs from normal scope in that it does not prototypically inherit from the parent scope. This is useful when creating reusable components, which should not accidentally read or modify data in the parent scope.
>
> = or =attr - set up bi-directional binding between a local scope property and the parent scope property of name defined via the value of the **attr attribute**. If no attr name is specified then the attribute name is assumed to be the same as the local name.

Note that for two-way data-binding, is expected that you pass your model as **attribute**.

When you do this (write your model as an attribute) it works like a charm (check [this fiddle](http://jsbin.com/pujuvaxu/2/edit)).

But you are passing your attribute via `ng-model`. It's already available on the scope of the directive. When you create a new scope, you are actually creating a **child scope** at your controllers scope and setting it to your `scope` parameter in the link function. In fact, if you watch the `$scope.$parent.name` it will work as well (check [this fiddle](http://jsbin.com/pujuvaxu/1/edit)).

Comment: I does work indeed. Can you please briefly explain what is going on in the directive link function and what is wrong with the new scope?

Comment: I mean to say: why is my new scope not used by the link function?

Comment: the new scope is used in link function, but when the directive uses isolated scope, it is no longer binded to the scope which you use in the controller out of the directive

Comment: Thanks doodec. Uhmm... I thought that there was a two-way binding with the `=` operator...

Comment: @balteo I added a little more text to my answer!

Comment: Just remember when using two-way data binding: "If it doesn't have a dot, you are doing it wrong."  remembering that has saved me from a lot of sticky situations.  Always pass an attribute.

Comment: @JHixson: Thanks. Ummm... I am not sure what you mean. Can you please kindly provide an example. Where do you see a dot?

Comment: @balteo `<input ng-model="name"\>` - Bad Idea.  `<input ng-model="customer.name"\>` - Good Idea